# Add parameter to method of interface and auto-add it in all implementing classes

Tags: visual-studio

is there a way in Visual Studio to add parameters to a method of an interface and Visual Studio will automatically add the parameter in all classes that implement this interface?

Comment: Could you tag the language you're asking about? I was assuming C# since we're talking about Visual Studio, but I suppose I shouldn't assume... Could you also clarify what you mean by "add parameters to an interface"? An interface doesn't have parameters. Do you mean something like adding a property to the interface, or perhaps a parameter to a method of the interface?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb edited

Comment: The immediate problem I see is that obviously if the interface is public there's no way of fixing projects outside of the solution. Disregarding that though, I don't think this is possible with out of the box VS. The best I'm finding is that you can have it add the changed method, but that doesn't help much since it's empty and leaves the old implementation as-is, which is more work than just adding the parameters yourself.

Comment: Even if this question could be answered, what's next?  How would you know what values to set for that parameter in all the other code that actually _calls_ this method with a new parameter?

Comment: I'm designing my own stuff here and I've already implemented the interface 45 times. I know it's not yet called from anywhere. I don't want to edit the method manually because doing so 45 times will be annoying. But if that's the only way, so be it. Yes, in an enterprise situation where  people use the code elsewhere, this would cause issues but I'm not doing so.